# Select specific area to split (bpy 2.8)

Tags: 3d-view

i'm new here.
I'm trying to implement an operator that creates and toggles a layout.
From the default "Layout" I would like to split the VIEW_3D into 7 separated VIEW_3D areas as shown below in red.[image: result to achieve by area splitting]
I'm using the command `bpy.ops.screen.area_split(direction='HORIZONTAL', factor=0.5)` many times but this operates always on the same area (top right at th end) reaching the result as shown below.
[image: Achieved result but not as wanted]

Is there a way to set the yellow area as active and continue by splitting it to reach the desired result?
I've tried overriding the context but that doesn't seem to work.

(Blender version 2.8)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but from this... I'd recommend creating a new layout and if you want to publish it save the blender file like that, or save it as the startup file